# Json.Net does not handle deserializing a null DataTable

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, jsonserializer

I have this class as object to serialize:

```
public class JsonServerToClient
{
    public JsonServerToClient()
    {
        query = new List<Query>();
    }
    public String authKey { get; set; }
    public List<Query> query { get; set; }

    public struct Query
    {
        public int error { get; set; }
        public DataTable result { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectAbove);` to serialize JSON.

and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonServerToClient>(text);` to deserialize it.

All works fine when the result is full of data, but if it is null I get this JSON:

```
{
    "authKey": "pippo",
    "query": [
        {
            "error": -1,
            "result": null
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is when I try to deserialize this I get an exception:

```
Eccezione non gestita di tipo 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Ulteriori informazioni: Unexpected end when deserializing array. Path '', line 1, position 56.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This issue was fixed in Json.Net version [8.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/8.0.1).  The workaround below is no longer needed.

---

It appears that the `DataTableConverter` that ships with Json.Net (as of v6.0.3) does not handle the case where the data table itself is null.  You can work around this issue by subclassing the `DataTableConverter` and overriding the `ReadJson` method like this:

```
class CustomDataTableConverter : DataTableConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
    }
}
```

When you deserialize, be sure to specify the custom converter:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonServerToClient>(json, 
          new CustomDataTableConverter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Json.NET are you using? As per this [post](https://json.codeplex.com/discussions/82097), it seems to be fixed with Json.NET 3.5r6

Comment: Runtime Version v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

I have same issues using Json.Net to parse DateTime field from the json response. I tried the following Json Helper class and it handled the datetime field properly.`public class JsonHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// JSON Serialization
        /// </summary>
        public static string JsonSerializer<T>(T t)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(ms, t);
            string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            ms.Close();
            return jsonString;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// JSON Deserialization
        /// </summary>
        public static T JsonDeserialize<T>(string jsonString)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
            T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
            return obj;
        }`